# Migration from native C++ to C++/CLI: new keywords conflict with old names

Tags: visual-studio-2010, migration, c++-cli

I am trying to add some CLI functions to an existing C++ library. In one of the includes a class defines

includedHeader.h:

```
class IncludedClass
{
    SomeType generic;
    SomeType specific;
}
```

This code compiles in C++, but the `generic` member name is now recognized as a keyword. Is there some way to disable the new sintax from parts of the code?

Edit: the compiler error are

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

both referring to the line with "generic".

Comment: You'll have to rename it, no other option.

Comment: I'd like to, but it's an header from a library which I can't compile.

Comment: Is this breaking compilation, or just highlighted wrong?  Those new keywords are supposed to be context-sensitive and not change the meaning of existing valid code.

Comment: Breaking compilation. I'll try and recover the compiler error as soon as I get back to work.

Comment: I edited teh question to add the warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are linking the compiled library, you can do something like this:

```
#define generic     __identifier(generic)

#include <includedHeader.h>

#undef generic
```

Comment: I can't try this solution right now, but I'm pretty sure that using `__identifier` shall solve the problem. Thanks!